# Daily data usage on home screen

Tags: mobile-data, app-widgets, data-monitoring

Can I see daily mobile data usage (excluding Wi-Fi) on the home screen using a widget?

Comment: Yes, with the help of third-party applications, I am not sure if the feature is available in stock, perhaps it depends on ROM

Comment: [Apps like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gibli.android.datausage) do this but as pointed out above not a stock Android feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this 3rd party widget will do it. It says that it can be customized.

[Data Counter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.datacounter/)

PS: Sorry for not using the comments field.